# Black, 'unknown', square pinned to dock in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, dock

How do I get rid of this 'unknown' program that is pinned to my dock? I have tried right clicking (which gets me nowhere), tried clicking it to bring it up and I get a black bar that I can't move or remove up around where the Activities button is and I have tried using 'xprop WM_CLASS' to identify it but it couldn't identify it. It doesn't go away if I restart and I have been through all my settings and nothing seems to be causing it. No idea what it is but it's taking up room.

Any suggestions?[image: Here is the black 'unknown' square]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the apps listed under `favorite-apps` in your `/etc/dconf/profile` or `~/.config/dconf/user` file.

You’ll see something like this:

```
[org/gnome/shell]
favorite-apps = ['gedit.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'nautilus.desktop']
```

Once you figure out what that black square belongs to, you can remove it by taking it out of the list above.

Source: [Gnome Help](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-favorite-applications.html.en)

Comment: This sounds like the right answer (and something I didn't know you could do) so I'll mark it as the right one but the black square just disappeared again the next time I fired up the laptop so I have no idea what it was but thank you for the help anyway:)